# Como lleno un vector sin tener un valor determinado, usando while en python

Tags: python, while, vectores

Un usuario debe ingresar medicamentos pero no se debe tener un numero predeterminado de cuantos medicamentos son, entonces se usa un while, al finalizar se debe organizar ascendentemente el vector c y u pienso que se hace asi:

```
import numpy as np
cpp=0
opc=int(input("Indique que desea hacer (1. Ingresar medicamento, 2. Salir)"))
while opc==1:
    n=1
    nm=np.zeros(n)
    f=np.zeros(n)
    c=np.zeros(n)
    u=np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        nm=input("Incluya el nombre comercial del medicamento:")
        f=input("Incluya la forma farmaceutica:")
        c[i]=int(input("Incluya la cantidad de principio activo por cada unidad dosificada en mg:"))
        cpp+=c[i]
        u[i]=int(input("Incluya la cantidad de unidades que tiene la presentacion comercial:"))
    opc=int(input("Indique que desea hacer (1. Ingresar medicamento, 2. Salir):"))
    n+=1
print(c[i])
print(u[i])
cpp/=n
for i in range(n-1):
    for j in range(n):
        if c[i]>c[j]:
            temp=c[i]
            c[i]=c[j]
            c[j]=temp
print("La cantidad total de registros fue", n,"\nLa cantidad promedio de principio activo fue",cpp)
print("Lista ordenada por principio activo",c)
```

Aunque al finalizar se muestra:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Carlos\Downloads\UNIVERSIDAD\FUNDAMENTOS DE PROGRAMACION\Programa de corte.py", line 23, in <module>
    if c[i]>c[j]:
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Una ayudita con el error

Comment: Para que iniciativas `nm` y `f` con ceros si luego vas a reemplazar su valor con un input?

Comment: partamos de la base que por cada ciclo la matriz solo va a tener un elemento, por más que repitas el bucle 100 veces, por lo tanto solo va a tener un elemento es imposible encontrar un segundo índice, la declaración de los array deberían estar fuera del bucle, después declaras la matriz de nombre nm y al rato le asignas una cadena, más allá de eso ¿para qué numpy para esto?

Answer (score 0):

```
#-*- coding: utf -8 -*-
import numpy as np

#nombre medicamento
nm=[]  
#forma farmaceutica
ff= []
```

éstas las declaro como listas, para el caso es lo mismo

```
#cantidad principio activo

cpa = np.array([],dtype=int)

#cantidad unidades comerciales

cuc = np.array([],dtype=int)
```

acá si las declaro como array de numpy, no hace falta que tengan valores, lo que si, usaré enteros, por lo tanto lo declaro

```
opc = int(input(f"""Indique que desea hacer."
1. Ingresar medicamento
2. Salir

>> """))

while opc == 1:
   
    nc = input("Incluya el nombre comercial del medicamento: ")
    nm.append(nc)
    f = input("Incluya la forma farmaceutica: ")
    ff.append(f)
    pa = int(input("Incluya la cantidad de principio activo por cada unidad dosificada en mg: "))
    cpa = np.append(cpa,pa)
    un=int(input("Incluya la cantidad de unidades que tiene la presentacion comercial: "))
    cuc = np.append(cuc,un)
    
    opc = int(input(f"""Indique que desea hacer."
    1. Ingresar medicamento
    2. Salir
    
    >> """))
```

las listas o arrays están fuera del bucle y solo les agrego el valor ingresado

```
print(f"""La cantidad total de registros fue: {len(nm)}
el promedio de principios activos fue: {np.mean(cpa)}
Lista ordenada por principio activo: {np.sort(cpa)}
""")
```

contamos los registros de las listas
sacamos el promedio con la función mean()
y por último ordenamos con la función sort()

pero como dije en los comentarios ¿para qué numpy y tantas listas o array o vectores? como quieras llamarlos.
Este trabajo sería mucho mejor con un diccionario.

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente no se que tratas de hacer, pues tampoco nombras a las variables de forma descriptiva, que es `f`? que es `c`, `cpp`? Otra cosa importante y creo que estas olvidando es que en cada iteración estas volviendo a inicializar los valores de tus `np.arrays` y siempre los agregas en la primera posición y no existen mas posiciones, pues en python no declaras los *array* con un tamaño y es mas, ni siquiera existe este tipo de dato, en su lugar existen las listas.

En este caso no utilice *Numpy* pues no es necesario, a menos que así lo quieras hacer. Para mi solución simplifique el ciclo `while` y le puse un mejor nombre a las variables

```py
medicamentos = []
while True:
    opc=int(input("Indique que desea hacer (1. Ingresar medicamento, 2. Salir):"))
    if opc ==2: break

    #datos del medicamento
    name=input("Incluya el nombre comercial del medicamento:")
    forma=input("Incluya la forma farmaceutica:")
    cant = int(input("Incluya la cantidad de principio activo por cada unidad dosificada en mg:"))

    unidades=int(input("Incluya la cantidad de unidades que tiene la presentacion comercial:"))

    #creamos una lista con la informacion del medicamento
    medicamento = [name,forma,cant,unidades]

    #añadimos a la lista general
    medicamentos.append(medicamento)

print(medicamentos)
```

Otra cosa que no me queda clara es en base a que quieres ordenar, pues dices que quieres ordenar `c` y `u` pero tu solo ordenas una, para esto tuve que inferir (gracias a un print) que lo que deseas es ordenar la lista en base al *principio activo* para eso utilizamos una función llamada `sorted` a la cual le podemos pasar un argumento llamado `key` para indicarle en base a que ordenara, y nosotros queremos que lo haga en base a *principio activo* que se encuentra en la posición 2 de nuestra lista.

```py
prom = sum([x[2] for x in medicamentos])/len(medicamentos) #sacamos el promedio
#ordenamos la lista
medicamentos_ord = sorted(medicamentos, key=lambda x:x[2])

#imprimimos
print("La cantidad total de registros fue", len(medicamentos),"\nLa cantidad promedio de principio activo fue",prom)
print("Lista ordenada por principio activo",medicamentos_ord)
```

Si no es necesario utilizar listas como estructura de dato, recomiendo que uses diccionarios, pues la información estará mas ordenada.

Answer (score 0):

Después de leer varias veces la pregunta al ver la llamada a *numpy* no comprendía que se buscaba.
La pregunta es:

> Como lleno un vector sin tener un valor determinado.

Pues eso sería tan fácil como con un `while True`, luego el `input` y si hay que salir un `break`.

```
lista_medicamentos = []
medicamento ={'nombre ': '','forma': '', 'cantidad': '', 'unidades': 0 }


while True:
    if 's' == input("Enter introducir datos, 's' para salir:\t"):
        break
    else:
        for dato in medicamento:
            medicamento[dato] = input(dato + ':\t')

        if 's' == input('guardar (s/n)'):
            lista_medicamentos.append(medicamento)
```

Ejecuta el código **siempre**. Luego le pides la condición para salir con el **break**.
Para simplificar no gestiono el tema de que vayas a introducir mayúsculas y los datos que pides los guardo en una lista de diccionarios, que no sé si es lo que quieres. Pero eso ya iría más alla de la pregunta (creo).

Comment: verdaderamente yo tampoco entendí por que usar `numpy` pero creo que es por que tiene que usar listas, por tal razón yo no use diccionario, pero eso seria un buen complemento a mi respuesta